# Devise Omniauth controller renders 404

Tags: devise, omniauth

## First scenario

### Controller

```
class Api::V1::AuthsController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def twitter; end

  private

  def callback
    user = User.find_or_authenticate_by_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], session['beta_signup_token'])

    if session['beta_signup_token'] 
      render json: {redirect: :complete_profile}
    else
      render json: {redirect: :stories}
    end
  end
end
```

### Routes

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      devise_scope :user do
        match 'auth/:provider' => 'auths#passthru', constraints: { format: :json }
        match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'auths#callback', constraints: { format: :json }
      end
    end
  end
```

### Response

```
Started GET "/api/v1/auth/twitter.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-02 14:43:32 -0500
Processing by Api::V1::AuthsController#passthru as JSON
  Parameters: {"provider"=>"twitter"}
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

## Second scenario

### Controller

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  before_filter :handle_authentication

  def facebook
  end

  def twitter
  end

  def linkedin
  end

  private

  def handle_authentication
    user = User.find_or_authenticate_by_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"],  session['beta_signup_token'])

    if session['beta_signup_token'] 
      redirect_to setup_profile_beta_invite_url(session['beta_signup_token'])
    else
      sign_in_and_redirect
    end
  end
end
```

### Routes

```
devise_for :users, constraints: { format: :html },
  :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

### Response

```
(twitter) Callback phase initiated.

Started GET "/users/auth/twitter" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-02 15:40:04 -0500
```

## My question

How can I make the first response the same as the second? I suppose in the first one, Twitter strategy is not being called, why?

I think my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15756523/1197775) is related